# Next.js Rewrite Issue with Next Link Component in Version 13.5.2

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js, url-rewriting, next.js13

I'm currently working on a multi-language website using Next.js, and I've been using rewrites to handle different languages. However, after updating to Next.js version 13.5.2, I've encountered an issue with rewrites when using the Next Link component.

Context:

This issue occurs when the application is deployed on Vercel, but it works perfectly fine in my local development environment.
The problem I'm facing is that when I use the Next Link component to navigate to a single page through a rewrite (e.g., /articles/123 rewritten to /artiklar/123), it doesn't work as expected. Instead, it only displays the navbar and footer, and the content of the page is missing.

To clarify:

1. When I click on a link generated by the Next Link component to go to a single page using a rewrite, it doesn't work properly.
2. If I use the original name of the single page folder in my application (e.g., /pages/articles/[id].jsx), the page loads correctly when accessed directly.
3. Interestingly, when I use an HTML  tag instead of the Next Link component,the page works as expected even with rewrites

I attempted to use an HTML  tag instead of the Next Link component, and with this approach, the issue does not occur. However, I would prefer to use the Next Link component for its benefits.

I suspect this issue is related to the recent Next.js update or perhaps a specific configuration on Vercel. Can anyone help me identify and resolve this problem specific to rewrites and the Next Link component? I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to get my single pages working with the Next Link component again.

Comment: you should share a reproducible code sample

Comment: @albing - Could you share the `rewrites` and `i18n` portions of your config?

Comment: please share rewrites and nextjs config you are working with.